# Windows refuses postgres connection

Tags: java, networking, jdbc, connection, jdbc-postgres

I have a local network connecting 15 PCs. Every PC has postgres installed (8.3, 8.4, 9.2). Every database has the exact same installation parameters as name, user, password, etc.

I'm using a Java application, which implements JDBC library and I have been able to connect correctly to the databases in EVERY computer but one. I'm pretty sure I have set correctly the necesary parameters for pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf, because they are set the same in all the 15 PCs.

I also have set the Windows Firewall exception for the port 5432

All this has lead me to conclude that the problem lies in that specific PC that doesn't accepts the connection. It has Windows 7 Ultimate installed, the same as the rest, and postgres 8.3.

This is the error that i get: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt timed out.

I don't want to format the PC from zero

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you connect to the database locally?

Comment: Yes, it works fine locally

Comment: this is the error that i get: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt timed out.

Comment: I'm also able to make a successfull cmd Ping remotely to the ip of the PC with issues

Comment: Have you tried after disablign the Windows firewall?

Comment: @ChrisTravers Yes, I have. Thanks for the interest

Comment: Is it possible that some internal firewall is filtering out the connection?

Comment: Well, I don't know of any firewall working besides Windows Firewall. Some time ago I had the same problem and the only solution was to format the PC. I can't do that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I know how to solve the problem with a not very orthodox solution. When this happens, we just copy the pg_hba.conf from a working PC and this solves the problem. I hope this helps.